# Setting up a GPS TCP server

Tags: router, tcp, route-server

I am working on a project where we are using a GSM modem with built in GPS system. The modem has setting to send GPS signal NMEA format to a remote TCP server.
Can someone consult on where should i start when creating this TCP server. If i have multiple units, how do i differentiate between them when receiving the data and etc. 
If there are any online links that could help me get started, that would work as well.
P.S. The router i am using is from Multitech MTR-H5-B08.

Comment: Welcome to NE!  Sadly, application questions, like setting up a time server, are off-topic here.  You can try asking on [sf].